# How can i compare arrays in two jagged arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, comparison, jagged-arrays

Ok so i have 2 jagged arrays, i want to loop through them and compare each array to every array in the other jagged array.
So in this example i want to return true when access[1] == visual[0].

But it seems i cannot explicitly compare arrays in the jagged arrays. How can i reference the arrays as a whole and not only the elements within those arrays?
By this i mean if i write `access[0][0]` i will get `"10"`. But i can't write `access[0]` to get `"10","16"`

```
string[][] access = new string[][] {
                    new string[] {"10","16"},
                    new string[] {"100","20"},
                    new string[] {"1010","2"},
                    new string[] {"1011","1"}
                };

string[][] visual = new string[][] {
                new string[] {"100","20"},
                new string[] {"101","36"},
                new string[] {"101","37"},
                new string[] {"101","38"}
            };
```

Comment: Your problem exists at the same level: you can't compare directly two `string[]` arrays... You have to compare them element by element...

Comment: And *But i can't write access[0] to get "10","16"*... In the same way, with a monodimensional array `string[] access = { "10, 16" }`, you can't write `access` to get `"10", "16"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But i can't write access[0] to get "10","16"

You can. But to compare the elements you need to use [Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(access[1], visual[0])) { ... }
```

Comment: Any idea on how to remove the array at `access[i]` once a match has been found?

Comment: I would use a `List<string[]>` instead of `string[][]` which would give you access to [`List.RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will do that!